# Вывести JS-код, как обычный текст

Tags: текст, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Какие в PHP существуют функции для обработки JS-кода, как обычного текста? Или какие хитрости, методы, способы? Как вы решили эту проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

тег **pre**

**UPD**
Точнее [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php) 
Передаёте этой функции код, он вам возвращает строку, которую можно безопастно вставить в HTML